# Has anyone used PhoneGap? What has your experience been with their service

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm trying to develop a mobile app I've been thinking about for a while. I want to know if anyone has used PhoneGap and what your experience has been with using their service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap is a framework for developing mobile applications using HTML and JavaScript.  It is not a "service" per se, though they do have some services available, like support and cloud builds, but I suspect that is not what you mean.

PhoneGap is a fine framework and can definitely get the job done if you need cross-platform support for your applications. But it does have some limitations too. So whether or not it will suit your needs depends on what you mobile application does.

If you application is a graphically intense game with real-time rendering, or heavy communications between peer devices or something, then PhoneGap might not be for you. However if your application does not require any of that and is more about using less intensive features of a phone (Contacts, GeoLocation, Accelerometer, LocalStorage) and your UI can be easily created using HTML and JavaScript, then I would say PhoneGap would be great for you.

Some would say that PhoneGap is fine for simple apps and that for really complex, robust stuff you need to go native. I am hesitant to say it is that simple. PhoneGap is capable of making very complex applications in terms of logic, UI, etc.

Where PhoneGap really shines is its ability to work on multiple platforms. If you need to support multiple platforms (iOS, Android, BlackBerry, etc) and do not have the resources to support multiple native code bases, then PhoneGap and the other cross-platform choices (Adobe AIR, Titanium, etc) are awesome choices.

That is the situation that I am in. I am a lone developer that needs to support 3+ platforms. There is no way that I am going to waste my time doing native development for iOS, Android, Blackberry, etc, when I can get exactly what I need with PhoneGap, AIR or Titanium. I can get what I need in a fraction of the time with MUCH less maintenance using one fo these frameworks.